vk_api, клавиатура
Что делать в таком случае
keyboard = Keyboard([[Text(" Я оплатил(а)")]], inline = True)

Я создаю клавиатуру, всё работает, но что делать если я хочу создать 5 кнопок с одинаковым текстом, я ловлю ответ через event.text, и из-за этого выполняется только 1 команда, возможно ли как-то это исправить?
